# Slow installation time with pip on raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, openssl

## Have anyone else experience slow installation times with pip on a raspberry pi?

After I installed python3.8 on my pi, it takes ages to install packages.
Can anyone see any mistakes in my installation process?

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
# build tools
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev\
 libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl

# SSL certificate
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

```sh
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tar.xz
```

```
tar -xf Python-3.8.6.tar.xz
cd Python-3.8.6
./configure
sudo make install
```

> Then I checked my install by running:

```
python3 -m test
```

> Updated pip

```
python3.8 -m pip install -U pip
```

> And now it takes ages to install the package `steinloss` which I don't understand

```sh
python3.8 -m pip install steinloss
```

Comment: I'm guessing that package (or some of its dependencies) have native code elements, that probably had pre-built binaries for 3.7 but not for 3.8, so all that time is spent building the native dependencies from source.

Answer (score 0):

Building from source can take forever in a Raspberry in some cases, you can use precompiled binaries form piwheel

Check if /etc/pip.conf has the following configuration

```
>     [global]
>     extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

You can find more info on https://www.piwheels.org/

NOTE: Piwheel has precompiled binaries up to Python 3.9